# Python: Multithreading and Classes

Tags: python, multithreading

I have separated my long running process into 3 separate classes to make things somewhat readable. So I make an instance of the first class which is a Thread, and then create an instance of the next class within in this class. Then I call the methods of this class and at this class creates an instance of the next class.

So its sort of a domino effect.

If I use this approach, will the 2nd and 3rd objects run in the same thread as the first object(since it is a Thread object?). That makes sense to me since the 2nd object is created within the Thread class.

Comment: Don't describe your code; show it.

Answer (score 0):

Running this

```
import threading
import os

class A:

    def run(self):

        print ("class: %s Thread: %s" % (self.__class__, threading.current_thread().getName()))
        b = B()
        b.run()

class B:

    def run(self):

        print ("class: %s Thread: %s" % (self.__class__, threading.current_thread().getName()))
        c= C()
        c.run()

class C:

    def run(self):
        print ("class: %s Thread: %s" % (self.__class__, threading.current_thread().getName()))

def main():

    print ("main function  Thread: %s" %  threading.current_thread().getName())
    a = A()
    a.run()

if __name__ == "__main__":

    print ("entry point  Thread: %s" % threading.current_thread().getName())

    t=threading.Thread(target=main)
    t.start()
```

prints

```
entry point  Thread: MainThread
main function  Thread: Thread-1
class: __main__.A Thread: Thread-1
class: __main__.B Thread: Thread-1
class: __main__.C Thread: Thread-1
```

So, if I understood your logic right the answer is **Yes**